# Error while casting to enumeration

Tags: java

I am trying to combine 4 files into a single file,using `SequenceInputStream` and `LinkedList` as data structure.

My error is

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.io.FileInputStream cannot be cast to java.util.Enumeration   at
>   faizal.Address.main(Address.java:21)

```
import java.io.*;

import java.util.*;



public class Address{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FileInputStream f1 = new FileInputStream("E://Ass.java");
        FileInputStream f2 = new FileInputStream("E://Ass1.java");
        FileInputStream f3 = new FileInputStream("E://abc.txt");
        FileInputStream f4 = new FileInputStream("E://ad.txt");
        LinkedList al = new LinkedList();
        al.add(f1);
        al.add(f2);
        al.add(f3);
        al.add(f4);
        Collections.synchronizedList(al);
        Enumeration e = (Enumeration) al.element();
        SequenceInputStream sq = new SequenceInputStream((Enumeration<? extends InputStream>) al);
        int i = 0;
        while((i=sq.read())!=-1){
            System.out.print((char)i);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: You can't just magically turn a `FileInputStream` into an `Enumeration` by casting it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your goal: you have 4 files, you want to concatenate. Format inside files doesn't matter. The way you use is useless (sic), and cant work, because your program cant guess magicly what is inside.

Then, just :

- read each one:

[Reading a plain text file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/best-way-to-read-a-text-file-in-java)

- I suppose it is texte (txt, java) : just append to String, and write in one shot to a file, like this:

[How do I create a file and write to it in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/how-to-create-a-file-and-write-to-a-file-in-java)

- or, write each one, and append to the file

[How to append text to an existing file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625234/how-to-append-text-to-an-existing-file-in-java)